# Unable to clone from bitbucket repository - Empty reply from server

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to clone a bitbucket repository, but receiving the following response:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://robertcas257@bitbucket.org/aerobotics/aeroview.git/': Empty reply from server
```

All other repositories in the project are able to be cloned, and I have checked that the permissions are the same.

Any ideas!?

Comment: It's apperantly a common problem, try to ***reboot*** your computer. Alternatively, some people report deleting *cache* from `.git` folder helps

Comment: @e.doroskevic thanks. Unfortunately neither of these worked - do you have any other ideas?